# Limit number of documents read

Tags: mongodb, realm

I've setup a database in [realm](https://www.mongodb.com/realm) and I was wondering, is there any way to enforce a limit on the number of documents a client is allowed to read?
I’ve found somewhere that a single read can be up to 50K docs, suppose I have a 150K collection, some client code can read my entire database in just 3 calls. Any way to prevent this?

Edit:

My MongoDB Realm App uses social login to authenticate its users and on the frontend I use `mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk` to query the database. My intention is to use the GraphQL API (with custom resolvers) but this doesn't really solve the original problem. Suppose an evil client "injects" the following:

```js
const client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(MONGO_APP_ID);
const mongodb = client.getServiceClient(
  RemoteMongoClient.factory,
  "mongodb-atlas"
);
mongodb.db("my-database").collection("my-items").find({
  ...
})
  .toArray()
  .then(result => console.log('result', result))
  .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
```

then it will bypass graph-ql and subsequently read all my collections. So I need a way to enforce (Rules/Filters/something) reads of at most, say 100 items/query. Furthermore, if the user goes wild again and tries to read the collections iteratively, Realm should block any read attempts beyond, say 50 queries/day. Can this be done using Realm's existing infrastructure? Any workarounds/ideas?

Comment: I posted an answer but based the edit, you're requiring authentication, right? And by that you can limit what data a user can access based on their auth using Rules. So in what context can an authenticated user, with [Rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/enforce-a-document-schema) in place 'inject' anything? More importantly though, if you want to limit the amount of data that can be read in a query, how would you determine what data? Say the query is for certain Dogs out of 10,000 Dogs collection. Which dogs should be returned? The first 100? the last 100? the first 100 sorted?

Comment: can you please post an update/example on how exactly you "can limit what data a user can access based on their auth using Rules"? as for the latter, I would just take the first 100 entries of each query

Comment: I don't want to repeat the documentation (as linked above) but looking at [aggregate functions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-aggregation/) like [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/index.html#dbcmd.count) and and especially [**limit**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/#dbcmd.count) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Results are lazily loaded so reading 150,000 objects into a Results is no big deal.

You can easily limit how many are actually loaded in memory by only giving access to a limited subset at a time.

For example; if you have a table that displays dogs; you can easily load all of the dogs into a Results, but then only display a certain number of dogs in the table.

I don't know your coding platform but at a high level...

```
let results = realm.objects(Dogs.self) //load all dogs

topDogIndex = 0
numberOfDogsToDisplayInTable = 20

table.show(topDogIndex to topDogIndex + numberOfDogsToDisplayInTable)
//in the above we initially show 0 to 20 so only 20 dogs are 'loaded' from Results
```

then when the user goes down a screen or however your UI works (pagination)

```
topDogIndex = topDogIndex + numberOfDogsToDisplayInTable 
table.show(topDogIndex to topDogIndex + numberOfDogsToDisplayInTable)
//this displays the next set of 20 dogs, again, only loading 20 from Results
```

With the above it makes no difference how many dogs there are in Results because you are only ever showing 20

You can easily modify the above to prevent more the X total dogs being read from Results by adding an IF statement - as in

```
if topDogIndex < 100 {
   // allow the tableView to scroll and access more Dogs
} else {
   print("Sorry, you're read 100 dogs already"
}
```

Comment: not sure you understood my problem entirely - i'm using MongoDB Atlas Realm and the question was whether i can configure it to prevent data theft? what you show here looks like client-side pagination... but can this be done in their platform?

Comment: @RobyRodriguez There is no product *MongoDB Atlas Realm*. You can have MongoDB Atlas or MongoDB Realm. The question does not reference data theft; it asks *is there any way to enforce a limit on the number of documents a client is allowed to read* and *...read my entire database in just 3 calls. Any way to prevent this?* My answer shows how you can manage how much data is read and can manage the number of calls. Realm offers Authentication and security which would *prevent theft*. Perhaps clarifying the question would help you get an answer to a more specific question?

Comment: Oh, and there are [Rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/enforce-a-document-schema) you can implement as well but something to consider is if you want to limit how much data is read bu a user, how do you determine *what* data should be read. Suppose there are 150,000 Dogs in your database, which Dogs should the user be able to access - only the first 50, all 150,000? Make things like queries less manageable when you're trying to 'protect' the data in that fashion.

Comment: thanks for the interest @Jay there's an edit to the question - hopefully this clears it up a bit