# SwiftUI Realm Memory issue. RAM usage keeps on increasing

Tags: swiftui, memory-leaks, realm

I am downloading over 7000 images that need to be saved to a Realm DB. I am writing to the DB in batches of 100. They are temporarily stored in an Array.

My issue is that as the process goes on, RAM usage keeps on increasing. I already wrapped the activity with autoreleasepool { activity }, but it keeps on happening.

```
func downloadImages() {
    autoreleasepool {
        realmQueue.async {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            print("6.5: Downloading Images")
            var x = 0

            var imageSavedArray : [ImageSaved] = []

            let imageUrls = self.urlPrep()

            for url1 in imageUrls {

                let imageURL = URL(string: url1)
                let placeholder = URL(string: "")
                let imageToSave = ImageSaved()
                if imageURL != nil {
                   
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                   
                    imageToSave.link = url1
                    imageToSave.data = data
                    
                    imageSavedArray.append(imageToSave)
                    
                }  else {
                    print("Invalid Saving Process for " + url1)
                }

                if ((x % 100) == 0) {
                    try! realm.write {
                       
                        realm.add(imageSavedArray)
                    }
                    imageSavedArray = []
                }
                x += 1
            }//end for
        }//end queue
    } //end autoreleasepool
} //end function
```

[This will continue until eventually it crashes.][1]

As soon as the process finalizes, the RAM goes back to normal.As you can see, I am resetting the array after writing it to Realm.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "They are temporarily stored in an Array."  It doesn't sound like a good plot.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: So I think my problem might lie in one of the two areas, maybe both.

1. imageSavedArray is kept on RAM after its reset with imageSavedArray = [:]

2. realm.write operation doesn't clean up until thread is released, hence increasing RAM usage.

Comment: Here's the issue `var imageSavedArray : [ImageSaved] = []`. Realm objects are lazily loaded which means thousands of objects take up almost no memory. As soon as you store them in an array, they *all take up memory* which can overwhelm a device as well as cause performance issues. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225254/swiftui-app-shows-realm-changes-but-not-new-objects/67232083#67232083) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990172/limit-number-of-documents-read/65997400#65997400) as well.

Comment: Jay, thanks for your answer. imageSavedArray is a temporary store for the images so they can be saved in groups of 100. This really optimizes the sync time. After writing the images to Realm, imageSavedArray is reset (I think that its still kept in memory after being reset).....ImageSaved is just the Object from Model, not the results.....I tried running the process without the array, writing each object to Realm as its created, this just takes more time and still runs up the RAM usage

Comment: I took a sec and formatted your code. If you'll notice, EVERYTHING is within the autorelease pool and that's not what you want; you'll want to wrap the 100 you are loading within an autorelease pool so they are dumped after they are saved. Rinse, repeat. FYI: Realm is NOT a good tool for image storage. While it may be ok for small thumbnails, it's not recommended. Find a service designed that for that. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268185/images-storage-performance-react-native-base64-vs-uri-path/67271381#67271381). The async may be in the wrong place as well.

Comment: Where exactly would you place the autoreleasepool? I have tried everywhere, wrapping only the write operation has no effect, wrapping the imageSavedArray declaration or the actual ImageSaved() object produces an error where it is not found in scope. Clearly I don't have a proper understanding of autoreleasepool usage, so any help is greatly appreciated. On the other hand, I need to persist the images for offline use, and I have found Realm to be more reliable and easier to write than CoreData and Filemanager approach. Other than this issue, the app performs pretty well.

Comment: Regarding the async, it might be the culprit of my problem, I have really struggled with the concept that Realm needs to be accessed from the same thread on every process you run. This is how I got everything else to work, creating a Realm exclusive thread that wasn't the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide an answer using generic code to keep it brief, and ignore the .async for this answer.

Also, this code assumes the number of urls in the array is a multiple of 10 to keep it short.

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: urlArray.count, by: 10) {
    autoreleasepool(invoking: {
        let smallUrlArray = myArray[i...i+9] //get 10 urls, start to fill pool
        var imageSavedArray = [ImageSaved]()
        for imageUrl in smallUrlArray {
            let imageToSave = ...create an ImageSaved object from the image and data
            imageSavedArray.append(imageToSave)
        }
        try! realm.write {
           realm.add(imageSavedArray)
        }
    }) //drain pool
}
```

In the code, iterate over the array of urls every 10 indexes using `stride`

Within that outside loop, create an autorelease pool

Within the pool an array of 10 urls is created and then iterated over - within that loop, create the realm objects to save, store in an imageSavedArray, then write them to realm.

At the end of the closure, the pool is drained, meaning anything created inside the autorelease pool is disposed of and memory is freed.

So the memory profile looks like this

```
       /|    /|
      / |   / |
     /  |  /  |
fill^   ^drain
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. That did it!!